# Does a Vietnamese with a US F-1 student visa need a visa to travel to Korea?

Tags: visas, south-korea, f1-visas, vietnamese-citizens

I'm currently an international student studying in the US. I'm Vietnamese and have an F-1 visa. I'm planning to take a round trip from Vietnam to Korea this summer and I was wondering about the visa requirements when I go.

Comment: Your F1 visa doesn't change the requirements for a Vietnamese visiting Korea.

Comment: @TheZealot It kinda does, though. The OP, as a holder of a US visa, could make use of the 30-day transit facility, if (and only if) traveling on a three-way ticket (eg NYC->ICN->SGN).

Answer (score 1):

While there are exemptions for those with a visa issued by certain countries, you must be en route to or returning from the country that issued that visa (or a third country). A round trip from your home country does not exempt you, and you would need to obtain a visa. You'll find the visa details and documents list on [Korea's Consulate in Vietnam](http://overseas.mofa.go.kr/vn-hochiminh-ko/brd/m_4020/list.do) website.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the 30-day transit facility, if (and only if) traveling on a three-way ticket: USA -> ICN -> VN. That will allow you to get a visa waiver up to 30 days.